# Choose derived class at runtime and run unique class method

Tags: c++, oop, derived-class, variant

Is it possible to choose a derived class at runtime and then execute a method which has different argument number/types? Example, we have base class `Fruit`

```
class Fruit{
    public:
        int weight;
        Fruit(int);
};

Fruit::Fruit(int w) : weight(w){};
```

with derived classes `Apple` and `Orange`

```
class Apple : public Fruit {
    public:
        void eat(int);
        Apple(int);
};

Apple::Apple(int w) : Fruit(w){};

void Apple::eat(int amount){
    weight -= amount;
};
```

```
class Orange : public Fruit {
    public:
        void eat(int, bool);
        Orange(int);
};

Orange::Orange(int w) : Fruit(w){};

void Orange::eat(int amount, bool peel){
    if (peel){
         weight /= 10;
    }
    weight -= amount;
};
```

They both have the method `eat` but with differing arguments. How can I choose which derived class to create at runtime and then execute `eat`?

```cpp
int main(){
    // read input i.e. (apple, 5) or (orange, 2, true)
    // create either apple or orange 
    // eat it
}
```

Comment: Well, you can use something like command pattern. Use constructor for parameters and then execute your action in virtual function.

Comment: What would happen if you typed in `(orange, 5)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use approach similar to `command pattern`. Pass different parameters through the constructor and execute different implementation of `eat` method when needed. Like this:

```
class Fruit {
  public:
  int weight;
  Fruit(int);
  virtual void eat() = 0;
};

Fruit::Fruit(int w) : weight(w){};

class Apple : public Fruit {
  public:
  void eat() override;
  Apple(int, int);
  int amount;
};

Apple::Apple(int w, int a) : Fruit(w){};

void Apple::eat() { weight -= amount; };

class Orange : public Fruit {
  public:
  void eat() override;
  Orange(int, int, bool);
  int amount;
  bool peel;
};

Orange::Orange(int w, int a, bool p) : Fruit(w), amount{a}, peel{p} {};

void Orange::eat() {
  if (peel) {
    weight /= 10;
  }
  weight -= amount;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal of polymorphism is to NOT know specific details about the object you are accessing.  In this case, since `Orange` has an additional `peel` action that `Apple` does not, I would take an approach more like this instead:

```cpp
class Peelable {
public:
    virtual void peel() = 0;
};

class Fruit {
public:
    int weight;

    Fruit(int weight) : weight(weight) {}
    virtual ~Fruit() = default;

    void eat(int amount) { weight -= amount; }
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
public:
    Apple(int weight) : Fruit(weight) {}
};

class Orange : public Fruit, public Peelable {
public:
    Orange(int weight) : Fruit(weight) {}
    void peel() override { weight /= 10; }
};

int main() {
    // read input i.e. (apple, 5) or (orange, 2, true)

    // create either apple or orange 
    Fruit *f = new /* Apple(5), Orange(2), ... */;

    // eat it
    Peelable *p;
    if ((p = dynamic_cast<Peelable*>(f)) && shouldPeel) {
        p->peel();
    }
    f->eat();

    delete f;
}
```